# Owl carousel plugin with filter MixItUp

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, mixitup

I'm trying to get these plugins to work together. I'm not sure if I'm better off modify MixItUp to work with carousel or other way round.

Owl Carousel - http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

MixItUp - https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");  

    carousel.owlCarousel();

    carousel.mixItUp({
        callbacks: {
            onMixStart: function(state){
                state.$show.parent().show();
            },
            onMixEnd: function(state){
                state.$hide.parent().hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJqwvr

Comment: Please if anybody can help with this I'm really stuck with it all. Even just some ideas on how to fix it and get me started